# regex to extract housenumber plus addition

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex that matches housenumbers combined with additions for all addresses below:

> ```
> Breestraat 4
> Breestraat 45
> Breestraat 456
> Dubbele Straat  4a
> Dubbele Straat 4-a
> 5 meistraat 1a
> 5meistraat 12
> 5meistraat 12a
> Teststraat 22-III
> ```

Now the following regex works, except in the first case. This is because the single digit housenummber is missed because of the first \d in the regex (which prevents a starting digit to be captured).

```
\d?.(\d+.+)$
```

[regex to extract housenumber addition](https://regex101.com/r/IgQpqp/1)

I'm scratching my head how to get the housenumer '4' for the first line. so basically how to change the "skip starting digit" to "skip starting digit but let it have to result on the capturing group".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
\d+\D*$
\d+\S*$
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/6WzwzC/1) and [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/6WzwzC/2).

The pattern matches

- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\D*` - zero or more non-digit chars
- `\S*` - zero or more non-whitespace chars
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: ah, that's it. Not that complex, just didn't see it right away. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not perfectly clear what you are requesting precisely..

Anyway this is the pattern matching the house number at the end of the string:

```
\d+[-\da-zI]*$
```

https://regexr.com/6l0g7

Anyway I'm aware this is not a valid answer